# Is it possible to have an array parameter with a default value?

Tags: delphi

With the latest version of Delphi, is it possible to have an array parameter with a default value?

```
procedure myProcedure(const AnArray: Tarray<integer> = [1,2,3]);
```

Comment: Depends on which version will be the last one - I doubt that [10.4 Sydney](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters) is it.

Comment: Also not supported in [11 Alexandria](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Alexandria/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters) which was released 9-Sep-2021.

Comment: thanks a lot, hope it's will be supported in futur release

Comment: You can work around that by having  two procedures (possibly `overload`-ed), where one forwards to the other.

Comment: Or simply add one line at the start of your routine that checks the length of the array and populates it.  `if (Length(AnArray)=0) then AnArray:=[1,2,3];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default parameters have to be constant expressions, as stated in the [documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Parameters_(Delphi)). And constant expressions cannot represent non-empty arrays.